# What is the different between Deploy Solution and Deploy?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio

I have been developing WP's for SP 2010 for some time now, and have not thought about a simple concept. What is the difference between deploying the solution vs deploy? What files are included when deploying the solution? Which should I be doing? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see two different options in Visual Studio 2010?  I only have one deploy option on the Build menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to the case when you have a Visual studio solution containing multiple projects. Deploy solution deploys all projects (WSP files) and Deploy just deploys the current project.